# How to update only one value in nested array of Redux state?

Tags: javascript, redux

Consider the following state:

```
const initState = {
    id: {
        data: null, 
        isFetching: false, 
        fetchingError: null
    },  
    bookmarks: {
        IDs: {
            news: [], 
            opps: [],
            posts: []           
        },
        data: {
            news: [], 
            opps: [],
            posts: []
        },      
        isFetching: false, 
        fetchingError: null
    },
    role: null,
    membership: null,   
}
```

How do I update just the `posts` array in the `ÌDs` array in the `bookmarks` array? I tried this:

```
case 'SET_USER_BOOKMARKED_POSTS':
    return {
        ...state, 
        bookmarks: {
            IDs: {
                posts: action.payload
            }
        }
    }
```

But when I log the state to the console the `IDs` array then only contains `posts`, while the `opps` and `news` arrays are not there anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to destruct all inner structure:

```
case 'SET_USER_BOOKMARKED_POSTS':
    return {
        ...state, 
        bookmarks: {
            ...state.bookmarks,
            IDs: {
                ...state.bookmarks.IDs,
                posts: action.payload
            }
        }
    }
```

But this is not very convinient, better use [lodash merge](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#merge)

Answer (score 2):

You need use the spread operator for `state.bookmarks.IDs` also as when specifies keys after the spread operator, the value for the keys are overwritten.

```
case 'SET_USER_BOOKMARKED_POSTS':
return {
    ...state, 
    bookmarks: {
        ...state.bookmarks
        IDs: {
            ...state.bookmarks.IDs,
            posts: action.payload
        },   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way we do it is a non-mutative method using `Object.assign` to basically point and update a field in the redux state. Something like:

```
return Object.assign({}, state.bookmarks, {
    IDs: action.payload,
});
```

This will make sure you're not mutating the state, and returns the new bookmarks. You can adjust this to return the entire state if you'd like, it depends on if you need the other data on the update.